# How is this while loop stopping the first part of the code to run?

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop

i am trying to wait to get user input using three buttons however when i try to use any while loop or for loop to wait for any of the buttons to be clicked for whatevr reason appears to skip the GUI code before it.

```
    import tkinter
    import time
    clickNum = 0
    gameLimit = 0
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("why does this not work?")
    def on_button_click(button_id):
        global clickNum
        clickNum = button_id
        print(clickNum)
    button1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "this", width = 10, bg = "white", height = 2, command = lambda:on_button_click(1))
    button1.pack(padx = 20, pady= 10, side = "left")
    button2 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "should", width = 10, bg = "white", height = 2, command = lambda:on_button_click(2))
    button2.pack(padx = 20, pady= 10, side = "left")
    button3 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "work", width = 10, bg = "white", height = 2, command = lambda:on_button_click(3))
    button3.pack(padx = 20, pady= 10, side = "left")
    button1.configure(text= "why?")
    button2.configure(text= "?")
    button3.configure(text= "?")
    clickNum = 0 
    while clickNum == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
    if clickNum == 3:
        x = 5
    elif clickNum == 2:
        x = 3
    elif clickNum == 1:
        x = 1
    clickNum = 0
    print(x)
```

no error messages appear
i want the code to wait until any of buttons are press

Comment: You can't use regular while loops to control flow with UI applications. You need to enter the Tk mainloop first.

Comment: have `on_button_click` do what ever it is you want to happen instead of manually waiting for it

Answer (score 0):

> How is this while loop stopping the first part of the code to run?

Tkinter is single-threaded, it can only do one thing at a time. While your loop is running, it's impossible for `clickNum` to change, therefore the loop never exits. That is because `time.sleep(1)` literally makes your program go to sleep. While the program is sleeping it can't respond to events, and responding to events is how GUI programs work. When you stop the flow of events, you stop the program.

> i want the code to wait until any of buttons are press

The way to do that is to call the `mainloop` method of the root window. That is specifically what it is for: to wait for events and then respond to them.

Remove your `while` loop and add the following to the end of your script:

```
window.mainloop()
```

While that function is running, your program will wait for and then respond to all events, including button events.

Answer (score 0):

These are starter mistakes(I made them), But you will be best served following a tutorial. Code that works gives confidence, especially at the beginning.

Read through the comments in the code.

```
import tkinter
import time
clickNum = 0
gameLimit = 0
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("why does this not work?")
def on_button_click(button_id):
    global clickNum
    clickNum = button_id
    print(clickNum)
    #tkinter is single threaded, you have to make sure that thread can talk to your functions, the way it was your x will throw an error
    print_x()
button1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "this", width = 10, bg = "white", height = 2, command = lambda:on_button_click(1))
button1.pack(padx = 20, pady= 10, side = "left")
button2 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "should", width = 10, bg = "white", height = 2, command = lambda:on_button_click(2))
button2.pack(padx = 20, pady= 10, side = "left")
button3 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "work", width = 10, bg = "white", height = 2, command = lambda:on_button_click(3))
button3.pack(padx = 20, pady= 10, side = "left")
#you have already set the button text above
#only do this if you want to change the values of the text already set
#button1.configure(text= "why?")
#button2.configure(text= "?")
#button3.configure(text= "?")
#while clickNum == 0: #your code will never go past this point as clickNum will always be zero as set above
    #time.sleep(1)
def print_x():
    global clickNum
    if clickNum == 3:
        x = 5
    elif clickNum == 2:
        x = 3
    elif clickNum == 1:
        x = 1
    clickNum = 0
    print(x)
#print(x) #cant use x here, it is not yet set
window.mainloop() #this is the mainloop @AKX was speaking about in the comment. without it tkinter GUI never shows up
```